# SQLite in Android How to update a select set?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
    UPDATE event
SET EVENT_PROCESS = 4
WHERE
    LEARNING_EVENT_GROUP_ID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            LEARNING_EVENT_GROUP_ID
        FROM
            event
        WHERE
            EVENT_TYPE = 1
        AND EVENT_PROCESS != 4
        AND (
            (
                (
                    EVENT_SEQUENCE = 1
                    OR EVENT_SEQUENCE = 2
                )
                AND 1463681631460 >= (
                    EVENT_EXPECTED_FINISHED_DATE + 86400000
                )
            )
            OR 1463681631460 >= (
                EVENT_EXPECTED_FINISHED_DATE + 172800000
            )
        )
    )
```

Here is my sql,
I want to update EVENT_PROCESS to 4 depends on the select set,but it didn't work on my project,without error. 
If SQLite does not support like this,What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you look at whether the `SELECT` query by itself returns anything useful?

Comment: @mindriot yes,and this sql works perfectly in Sqlite Browser(Navicat for Sqlite)